# Django hello world page not found on virtual machine OPENSTACK

Tags: django, ubuntu, http-status-code-404, openstack

The problem is that I test the **django helloworld** on two virtual (ubuntu server) machine.

one's virtual ip is xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx(example 123.4.5.6), 
physical ip is yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy(example 9.87.6.5),

another is xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx(example 123.4.5.7)
physical ip is yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy(example 9.87.6.4),

all these are static "virtual ip"
and static ip

The problem is,
while loading the page of the first django helloworld, everything is fine
(these two helloworld are same coded and are independent to each other),

but when I try building the second django helloworld and connect to the server it said

> Page not found (404)
>
> Request Method:   GET
>
> Request URL:  http://9.87.6.4/http:/9.87.6.4/
>
> {'path': 'http://9.87.6.4/'}
>
> You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django
>   settings  file. Change that to False, and Django will display a
>   standard 404 page.

and the server debugger said

> Performing system checks...
>
> System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
>
> November 30, 2017 - 12:13:18
>
> Django version 1.11.7, using settings 'helloworld.settings'
>
> Starting development server at http://123.4.5.7:80/
>
> Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
>
> Not Found: /http:/9.87.6.4:80/
>
> [30/Nov/2017 12:13:19] "GET http://9.87.6.4:80/ HTTP/1.1" 404 1666

Notice that there's an extra http:/9.87.6.4/
in the Request URL

I have tried reinstall the apache2

(but most likely it is not related to apache2 but to the virtual machine I think)

and it still didn't work.

my virtual machine is based on OPENSTACK.

since sometimes the django-debugger even print things like

```
[30/Nov/2017 12:37:58] "GET http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages HTTP/1.1" 400 61127
Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'windowbox.me'. You may need to add 'windowbox.me' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
```

or

```
[30/Nov/2017 12:37:58] "GET http://google.com HTTP/1.1" 400 61127
Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'google.com'. You may need to add 'google.com' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
```

when I visit the google page using the physical machine(not the virtual one) after visit the problem virtual machine,

so I am thinking maybe there's some false setup on my second virtual machine.

By the way, if I use lynx from my first virtual machine to visit the helloworld page in the problem virtual machine, EVERYTHING IS FINE. there's no http 404 and no duplicate URL

Comment: 2 things might be wrong: first, `Request URL: http://9.87.6.4/http:/9.87.6.4/` looks weird. This is not a legal URL basically. Secondly, have you opened the port 80 in your OpenStack security group?

Comment: Yea I have set the firewall correctly